# What is the meaning of "later on the day"

Tags: meaning, time

The sentence is

> Please note that only candidates who actually pass the tests will receive a notification by email **later on the day**.

I would like to ask that "later on the day" is when?
Is that specified like the next day?

Comment: At a later time of the day.

Comment: Later is a general word, not specifying a time. Later *in* the day means before the end of the same day. But it is not a guarantee.

Comment: To be clearer it should be "later on the _same_ day"

Comment: Or: .....later on in the day.

Comment: Or *later on that day* or *later that day* or any of a number of things. It *could* be any of those or the above, but it's perfectly acceptable as *later on the day* where *later on the day **of the test*** is logical but omitted.

Comment: @Robusto "later on the day" without "of the test" sounds very "off" to me

Comment: @Kevin: YMMV. I find it within the range of possible expressions. It wouldn't be my first choice, but if someone said it I would understand the intent within milliseconds.

Comment: @Robusto Google's Ngrams have "later on the day" as 1/400th as common as "later in the day" and I'm guessing that most of those rare instances are part of a larger phrase like the aforementioned "later on the day of the test" or "later on the day in question"

Comment: @Kevin: I said it was *possible*, not likely. But my comment still stands. And Google's NGrams [is not as unimpeachable a source](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu) as many people suppose. Even if it were, your effort does not prove that the expression is impossible. Quite the contrary: you have demonstrated that people do actually use it.

Comment: I also read it as an odd, but possible, abbreviation of "later on the day of the test". "On the day" is, in British English at least, a phrase that is used eg "I will let you know on the day". "The day" refers to a particular day which may be deduced from context.

Answer (score 22):

"Later on the day" is non-idiomatic in my opinion. I would assume they meant later the same day, but I would phrase it either "later in the day" or "later on in the day".

Comment: Yes. I read it as an error. Possibly a typo intended to be “later in”

Comment: I agree. It could be "later on that day" too

Comment: "Later that day", the on is unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe also _later on that day_.

Comment: "On the day" is often used when referring to a particular date in the future.

Comment: @StuartF Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure about this but I believe that "on the day" is correct when used in respect of a date that has been referenced before the phrase is used. The referenced date could be the current date, in the past or even in the future.

Like I said, not sure - just my tuppence ha'penny's worth!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"Later on the day" is not very common and doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Longman Dictionary only lists "[later in the day](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/later)":

> **later in the day/week/year**
> *The dentist could fit you in later in the week.*

Google Ngrams has [the following result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=later%20in%20the%20day%2Clater%20on%20the%20day&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

[image]

As you see, "later on the day" is almost non-existent. In fact, upon further examination, you can see that the majority of the examples have nothing to do with our case, e.g. "Later, on the day of the battle..."

Google search results seem to show a similar trend:

> "do it later in the day": 1,400,000 search results
> "do it later on the day": 2 search results

> "announce it later in the day": 14,100 search results
> "announce it later in the day": 1 search results

> "by email later in the day": 6,630 search results
> "by email later on the day": 4 search results, (one of which is this very page)

However, the picture somewhat changes if we search for the following:

> "announced later in the day": 213,000 search results
> "announced later on the day": 42,900 search results

Here "announced later on the day" is doing much better than before constituting around 17% of the results. I had a quick look at the results and here is what I have - tentatively - observed:

There are some search results of the type:

> "will be announced later. On the day of the launch am I going to".

But I think the majority of the results are of the following two types:

> "Winners will be announced later on the day of event."
> "with the winners of the President's Prize announced later on the day."

Based on the above, I tend to agree with KillingTime, Robusto, Kevin, StephenR, KeithLoughnane, among others.

To sum-up, I think **"later in the day" is the much more common/idiomatic form**, but some people seem to use "later on the day" as a sort of short form for "later in the day on a specific day". This is more common with announcing results, winners, etc but perhaps with some other verbs or situations that I have not considered.

Answer (score -4):

Later on the day is a correct phrase which is used to express something is happened, done or will be done after something else on that same day.